# Is it possible to embed an Excel worksheet alongside a Visio drawing in a webpage and interact across them with the office-js apis

Tags: excel, office-js, visio

I would like to build a webpage with 2 embedded iFrames - 1x Visio and 1x Excel and use the Visio.run and Excel.run office-js mechanisms to interrogate and interact across them in Office 365.

After various permissioning bug issues I now have Visio javascript code working nicely but cannot see how to get Excel working in a similar manner and I suspect I might have to host an embedded Visio drawing within an Excel task pane rather than having them as peer iFrames.

Embedding a Visio Online task pane within an Excel workbook would be ok provided it can then be rendered in Excel online via Office 365/Sharepoint

Are either or both of these options possible ? I cannot find any relevant samples published to achieve this so pointers would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

**Previous response** (This applies if you are trying to embed Excel workbook inside of a web-page with cross IFrame communication to refresh data/update the views):

There is no way to programmatically produce Excel embed links. Beyond that you'd need cross Iframe communication via. JS APIs to talk to Excel APIs, which is also not available. Both are under consideration but no defined plan. Please add your ask [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/)

*Update*

Embedding Visio online taskpane within workbook as a taskpane may work. However, the workbook view/data changes resulting from taskpane interaction would need to take place from background server round-trip, and not through Office-js. Or, the taskpane would need to orchestrate the communication using socket based communication. The experience may not be snappy.

Comment: Thanks Sudhi - how viable would it be in the interim to use Websockets via some sort of Node broker - are there any known hidden gotchas with promises etc ?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. Check my edited response.